# How can I properly print an object containing strings and multiple arrays in PowerShell?

Tags: arrays, powershell, oop, printing, format

I have an object named `$PersonObject` that contains as memebrs a name and two arrays of smaller objects.

I can print everything separately just fine, as in:

```
Write-Output $PersonObject.Name
Write-Output $PersonObject.FirstArray | Format-Table -AutoSize -Wrap
Write-Output $PersonObject.SecondArray | Format-Table -AutoSize -Wrap
```

But I would rather just be able to print all this information in one command by accessing `$PersonObject`. I want the name and both of my arrays present cleanly together, so I can convey to users it is one object they are seeing. And I'd like the arrays to be presentable in either list or table format, without truncation. I'd want this backwards comaptible with PowerShell v2, as well.

Is this possible, or am I going to have to go with three separate `Write-Output` commands?

Comment: Hmmm I guess you want to see this: [Custom Formatting Files](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878272(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PowerShell formatting cmdlets allow you to mix "real" properties with the one that you calculate "on the spot". In this case perhaps that would give you some ideas/ direction:

```
 $personObject | Format-List Name, @{
     Name = 'FirstArray'
     Expression = { $_.FirstArray | Format-Table | Out-String }
 }, @{
     Name = 'SecondArray'
     Expression = { $_.SecondArray | Format-Table | Out-String }
 }
```

Alternatively, you may want to look into `Format-Custom` - that one is able to show more complex objects as a JSON-like structure. Not perfect, but helps to understand deeply nested objects.

Comment: I'll look into this. Do you know if there's a way I can return the object, without losing its "objectness"? I want to be able to print everything nicely to the screen, but I don't the object to behave any differently than if I just did `$PersonObject` at the end of the function. From what I understand, formatting as a table will make the object be interpreted as something else when returned.

Comment: Take a look at FormatPx (https://github.com/KirkMunro/FormatPx or https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/FormatPx) - awesome module from Kirk Munro. It should probably give you what you need.